# Regular expression for exposed filter in a view [Drupal 8]

Tags: php, regex, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I am trying to filter out a result in a Drupal 8 view [Exposed Filter] using a regular expression. What I need is to search the keyword in the last 4 or 5 digits/letters of a specific field.

For example:

- 2006ABC00022
- 2014DEF03120
- 2019GHI03128
- 2019GHI07437

These are the data I need to filter. If someone tried to search `"0022"` I want to show the result as `2006ABC00022`. Because the last 4 digit is 0022. We can use `Ends with` operator to do this. But I want something different because If someone tried to filter the result with `"312"` I want to show the results as `2014DEF03120` and `2019GHI03128`. Because these 2 strings have `312` as starting of the last 4 digits. This scenario will not work if I use 'Ends with' operator. So I go for a regular expression.

`"[0- 9]{4}$"`

I tried to use the regex with the above one. And I realize that this is not working as I expected. This one is searching all over the string.
If I search for `2019` it shows the last 2 results. But it should be empty.

I just want to search the keyword on the last 4 digits. And if the keyword is 5 digit search for the last 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a valid match here is a keyword starting with a four digit year, followed by three letters, then followed by 5 digits.  This implies the following pattern:

```
\b\d{4}[A-Z]{3}\d{5}\b
```

Specifically, if you wanted to find matches ending in `0022` then modify the above pattern and use:

```
\b\d{4}[A-Z]{3}\d0022\b
```